# Change in coefficients when another factor is included in SEM

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, regression-coefficients

I have a question. Let's say in an SEM model, there is a significant relationship between A and B: `A-> B (beta=.400)`. Sometimes if I add another factor (i.e., C) the coefficient value between A and B can become very small or even non-significant: `A->b (beta=.100), C->B (beta=.380)`.

However, I do not know how to interpret or read this. Can someone help?

Comment: Is A -> B a regression?  If you add predictors to a regression equation, you expect the parameters to change. This is true whether the predictors (and outcomes) are latent variables or not.

Comment: @JeremyMiles yes it is a regression (within SEM model)

Comment: Do you want additional clarification, or is that explanation enough?

Comment: @JeremyMiles just to make sure: so, very probably this is about multicollinearity, right? In other words: the variability explained by A is probably largely accounted for by B, is this is a good summary of the situation do you think?

Comment: I wouldn't call it multicollinearity (because that implies a problem), but yes, A and C are correlated, and that's having the effect - but that's what is supposed to happen with regression.

Comment: @JeremyMiles so you mean this is probably multicollinearity, but you would not name it since it has negative connotations ?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by collinearity. If you mean collinearity is any correlation between predictors, then yes. But that's not what is usually meant by collinearity. But there isn't a level at which you can say a correlation is collinearity.